# openldap supplementary groups not showing up on certain servers

Tags: ldap

I have a couple of servers that fail to display newly added supplementary groups.  For example,  I have a user which you run `id` and his groups come up.

```
id <username>  
groupblah, groupblahblah , groupblahblahblah
```

They show up initially, but if you add that user to an LDAP group, for example hr_managers, on ldap it shows he's a member but on some servers, if you run id command,

```
id <username>
groupblah, groupblahblah , groupblahblahah   #( but no hr_managers)  show up

getent passwd ; displays the user 
getent group ; displays hr_manager
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to resolve this? Better yet, how does the ldap server go about getting this group information.  Would the nss_group search have anything to do with it?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have nscd running on your servers. Try `nscd -i passwd` and `nscd -i group` to flush its caches.